# i-nigma sdk/source code

Tags: android, ios, sdk

I have the i-nigma sdk and source code for Android and iOS and I dont know what to do with that I need to add some things to the app change the design and more I have all the needed files I need to make the app those things:

- Can scan code from the Library
- Ability to scan a code and to act in accord content revealed
- Ability to generate code with photo
- History and Popular
- Ability to share Facebook, email, SMS, etc.
- The ability of advertising within the application module
- Ability to push messages
- Competition with prizes Scanners
- Referrals management system through the application

The most of them are build in the sdk/source code

Comment: from where you got source code of  i-nigma sdk and source code

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact to 3GVision support:
http://www.i-nigma.com/qr-barcode-reader-sdk.html
I think they will help you with integration of SDK if you got it from them of course.